# SQL Select Case with Dynamic Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, getdate

I'm really not sure how to do the query I am looking for and was hoping someone could help me out.  Basically I want exactly what this query below does, except to use them with a dynamic year so that I don't need to update the SPROC everytime the year changes;

```
   SELECT 
    case 
    when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(),1) between '01/01/2013' and '03/31/2013' then '04/01/2013 - 06/30/2013' 
    when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(),1) between '04/01/2013' and '06/30/2013' then '07/01/2013 - 09/30/2013'
    when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(),1) between '07/01/2013' and '09/30/2013' then '10/01/2013 - 12/31/2013'
    when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(),1) between '10/01/2013' and '12/31/2013' then '01/01/2014 - 03/31/2014'
    end
```

I want this to function like

```
when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(), 1) between '01/01/currentYear' and '03/31/currentYear' then '04/01/thisyear - 06/30/currentYear'
```

if anyone could give me a little help on this that would be great.
Thank you very much,
NickG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the year as a parameter:

```
DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(4)
SET @YEAR = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())

SELECT 
    case 
    when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(),1) between '01/01/'+ @YEAR and '03/31/'+ @YEAR then '04/01/'+@YEAR+' - 06/30/'+@YEAR 
    when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(),1) between '04/01/'+ @YEAR and '06/30/'+ @YEAR then '07/01/'+@YEAR+' - 09/30/'+@YEAR
    when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(),1) between '07/01/'+ @YEAR and '09/30/'+ @YEAR then '10/01/'+@YEAR+' - 12/31/'+@YEAR
    when Convert(varchar(8), getDate(),1) between '10/01/'+ @YEAR and '12/31/'+ @YEAR then '01/01/'+@YEAR+' - 03/31/'+@YEAR
    end
```

Comment: that's perfect, im just going to use the year(getDate()) to get this year and set a second parameter as year + 1 basically.  I am in no way a DBA so thank you very much!

Comment: @NickG I have edited my answer to include the GETDATE() function, this way you still only need the one parameter

Comment: You need to add 1 to the year for the last `WHEN` section, it's supposed to be Q1 of next year, not Q1 of the same year.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using a `CASE` statement at all:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),(DATEADD(quarter, 1+DATEDIFF(quarter, 0, GETDATE()), 0)),1)+ ' - ' 
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),(DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(quarter, 2+DATEDIFF(quarter, 0, GETDATE()), 0))),1)
```

To confirm it works on other dates:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2012-12-10'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),(DATEADD(quarter, 1+DATEDIFF(quarter, 0, @date), 0)),1)
        + ' - ' 
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),(DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(quarter, 2+DATEDIFF(quarter, 0, @date), 0))),1)
```